# Crystal Reports - Embedding an either or condition on open

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal Reports Novice Checking in

I honestly am not sure whether this is possible.

I have been asked to change a report, so that if the user selects an option from a prompt/Parameter field, it converts certain / other parameter fields to text boxes.

Now, the easiest approach to this to me, would just be to have a separate report which a user could then select from whichever viewer/desktop.

Is there a way to actually do this within CR? because the solution beyond a separate report seems quite over engineered.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for an outright solution, but I don't know whether it is possible to get CR to behave in this manner.

Comment: Have your tried creating a parameter field that accepts and Yes/No or True/False value, and then creating one set of sections that contain version A of the report and another set of sections that contain version B of the report?  Then use the Suppress property of those sections to use the parameter field to determine which set to print at runtime.  Depending on the complexity of the report there could be some performance issues, but it should work.

Comment: R. This is exactly what I'm attempting to do. The only issue is i need to try and do this, ideally, prior to the parameters being requested. I can work with it if this isnt exactly possible however.